# EF many-to-many

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

How to build these tables for EF?

First table :

```
public class model1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Second table :

```
public class model2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Table which has a connection of the first and second
and several fields :

```
public class model3
{
    public int (id from model1){ get; set; }
    public int (id from model2) { get; set; }
    public int (id from model2){ get; set; }
    public decimal Name{ get; set; }
    public decimal Description{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this may do the trick (provide the table structure you described)

```
public class model3
{
    public virtual model1 Model1 { get; set; }
    public virtual model2 Model2 { get; set; }
    public virtual model2 SecondModel2 { get; set; }

    // if you want the ID fields explicitly,
    // EF will map the keys by property name, 
    // optionaly you can use the ForeignKeyAttribute
    public int Model1Id { get; set; }
    public int Model2Id { get; set; }
    public int SecondModel2Id { get; set; }


    public decimal Name{ get; set; }
    public decimal Description{ get; set; }
}
```

But you may want to rethink the structure - the one you presented looks a bit suspicious - model1 and model2 have the same fields, so maybe they shouldn't be defined as separate classes. The model3 class also has some common fields, so maybe it would be worth extracting them into a common class - EF handles inheritance.

To get a many to many relation though, you need something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars {get;set;}
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos {get;set;}
}
```

this will create a Foo table, a bar table and a FooBars (or BarFoos) associacion table.

Comment: ok, and to model1 and model2 i must add public virtual ICollection<Model3> Model3s{ get; set; }?

Comment: my context
 

    public DbSet<model1> model1s{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<model2> model2s{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<model3> model3s{ get; set; }

from how can i want get something like context.model1s. (and Name of SecondModel2Id )

Comment: take a look at this http://vincentlauzon.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/entity-framework-4-1-many-to-many-relationships-5/. The many-to-many relation is explained in detail there